# combine multiple sqlite database with same structure

Tags: java, sqlite, intellij-idea

I have mutliple sqlite database with the same structure hosted on localhost.I need to add all data  to one DB . the data may have same PK, so it is important not to replace data but only adding new data  and assign new PK if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way that this would work is if the primary key is defined as `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` and there is no need to create and update a temporary table.

After you attach `db2` execute this statement:

```
INSERT INTO mytable(col1, col2, ....) 
SELECT col1, col2, .... 
FROM db2.mytable;
```

By enumerating all the columns **except the primary key** you will insert all the rows of `db2.mytable` in `mytable` and a new value will be assigned to their primary key column.

Answer (score 0):

First *attach* `db2` and then:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp AS SELECT * FROM db2.mytable;

UPDATE tmp SET id = NULL;

INSERT  INTO mytable SELECT * FROM tmp;

DROP TABLE tmp;
```